# MVC ajax return string as [object] object

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

This is my ajax code which submit a formdata with a file.
if i remove always my custom string "has" file which will works and return "1234567".i am expecting to return has "has file 1234567" but always throw [object] object

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
     $('#scan').change(function (e) {
         debugger

         var element = this;
         var formData = new FormData();
         var totalFiles = document.getElementById("scan").files.length;

         var file = document.getElementById("scan").files[0];
         formData.append("scan", file);
         $.ajax({
             url: '@Url.Action("scancode", "Products")',
             type: "POST",
             dataType: "json",
             data: formData,
             processData: false,
             contentType: false,
             success: function (data) {

                 $('#barcode').val(data);                   
             },
             error: function (err) {

                 document.getElementById('emsg').innerHTML = err;
             }
         });
     });
});
```

**Controller**

```
 public string scancode(HttpPostedFileBase scan) {
        var str = "";
        if (scan !=null)
        {
            str = "has file";
        }

        try
        {


        IBarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader();
        // load a bitmap
        var barcodeBitmap = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(scan.InputStream);
        // detect and decode the barcode inside the bitmap
        var result = reader.Decode(barcodeBitmap);
        // do something with the result
        if (result != null)
        {
            str =str+ result.Text;
        }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            str = ex.Message;
        }
        return str;
    }
```

Comment: check whether you are getting a 200 OK response for your ajax call

Comment: You cannot actually return a string from an ajax call. Return a JSON object instead. Change the return type to JsonResult: `public JsonResult scancode(HttpPostedFileBase scan)` and instead of `return str;` return the Json: `return Json(new { someString = str });` and in your ajax call: `success: function (data) { $('#barcode').val(data.someString); }`

Comment: is the `dataType: "json",` correct in this case ? I don't think files can be posted via ajax....can someone correct me.

Comment: Since you specify `dataType: "json"`, your method should be `public JsonResult scancode(...)` with `return Json(str);`

Comment: i am getting 500 with post and 200 with Get.But i should be using Post right?

Comment: @Kapobajza do you mind posting it as answer? so that i can mark it.By the way. why if the str="123456" return successfully yet str="has file 1235" throw error?

Comment: @AizhongChen, Because you have specified `dataType: "json"` and your sending back a string with spaces in it which will be interpreted as 3 items (note all it needs to be is `return Json(str);` and keep `$('#barcode').val(data);`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to always return a `JsonResult` from a controller to the ajax query. Simply convert the string to `JsonResult` by using `Json(stringvalue);`

Your code will become :

```
public JsonResult scancode(HttpPostedFileBase scan) 
{
    var str = "";
    if (scan !=null)
    {   
        str = "has file";
    }
    try
    {
        IBarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader();
        // load a bitmap
        var barcodeBitmap = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(scan.InputStream);
        // detect and decode the barcode inside the bitmap
        var result = reader.Decode(barcodeBitmap);
        // do something with the result
        if (result != null)
        {
            str =str+ result.Text;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        str = ex.Message;
    }
    return Json(str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot actually return a string from an ajax call. Return a JSON object instead. 
Change the return type to `JsonResult`:

```
public JsonResult scancode(HttpPostedFileBase scan)
```

And instead of `return str;` return the Json:

```
return Json(new { someString = str });
```

Finally your ajax call should look something like this:

```
success: function (data) { $('#barcode').val(data.someString); }
```